# Having issues with npm in powershell terminal

Tags: node.js, npm

so im fairly new to the coding world and currently on a project for my web dev bootcamp.  im having an issue with using npm in my powershell terminal. This happened suddenly after deleting a couple of programs ( that i dont think had anything to do with npm or maybe it did?) off my control panel. Here is a screenshot of how it looks on my end. Does anyone know how to fix this?

i tried rerunning a different version npm to see if that would do anything and wouldn't work.

Comment: we can't see the screenshot...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.